# Passing values into a sharedClient

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have created a sharedClient

```
+ (id)sharedClient {
static MyClient *__instance;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:BASE_URL];
    urlComponents.user = @"username";
    urlComponents.password = @"password";
    NSURL *url = urlComponents.URL;
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    __instance = [[MyClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
});
    return __instance;
}
```

But as you can see I have hardcoded the username and password. What is the best way to pass variables into this class and the sharedClient? Currently I am calling the client like so

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
[SVProgressHUD show];

[[MyClient sharedClient]getPath:@"/users/current.json"
                           parameters:nil
                              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                                  NSString *authToken = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"user.api_key"];
                                  [self.credentialStore setAuthToken:authToken];

                                  [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

                                  [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"loginSuccess" sender: self];

                              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                  if (operation.response.statusCode == 500) {
                                      [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Something went wrong!"];
                                  } else {
                                      NSData *jsonData = [operation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                                           options:0
                                                                                             error:nil];
                                      NSString *errorMessage = [json objectForKey:@"error"];
                                      [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:errorMessage];
                                  }
                              }];


    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```

I have been thinking about instance variables but unsure what the best way to do this would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring two sharedClient methods where one uses the other but provides more info.  For example

```
+ (id)sharedClient {
    return [self sharedClientWithUserID:@"default user" andPassword:@"default password"];
}

+ (id)sharedClientWithUserID:(NSString *)userID andPassword:(NSString *)password {
    //move your dispatch once code here and use the provided userID and password
}
```

you could also have sharedClient pass nil for userID and password and then inside your other method check for nil and provide some default value.

Another possible choice, since you don't appear to need userID and password for the init call is to just declare them as properties and manually set them

```
[yourClass sharedClient].userID = @"id";
[yourClass sharedClient].password = @"password";
```